# How do I override a JBoss module with my own from my WAR file?

Tags: jboss, overriding, classloader, jboss7.x, war

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 and trying to deploy a WAR file using Apache Commons Lang 3.3.  The JAR is located in my WEB-INF/lib folder in my WAR file.  However, when I run my web application, I get the below error/exception and I think that's because JBoss is using its own older commons-lang library . How do you override the JBoss commons lang module without modifying the JBoss installation?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createTrainingLink(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:387)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.addUserLinks(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:352)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:205)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createTrainingSessions(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:162)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createOrUpdateTrainingSessions(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:124)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy132.createOrUpdateTrainingSessions(Unknown Source)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.quartz.ProcessPDWorker.work(ProcessPDWorker.java:23)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.controller.IndexController.refreshPD(IndexController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils from [Module "deployment.didoclient.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createTrainingLink(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:387)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.addUserLinks(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:352)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:205)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createTrainingSessions(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:162)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createOrUpdateTrainingSessions(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:124)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy132.createOrUpdateTrainingSessions(Unknown Source)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.quartz.ProcessPDWorker.work(ProcessPDWorker.java:23)
    org.mainco.subco.dido.controller.IndexController.refreshPD(IndexController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: It may be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293402/jboss-how-can-to-exclude-javax-validation-in-jboss-deployment-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks as if your code (or at least the code in `org.mainco.subco.dido.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl`) still uses an older version of commons-lang. If you check out the [Javadoc for commons-lang 3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html) you'll see that the code is under `org.apache.commons.lang3` instead of `org.apache.commons.lang3`.